# Canonical bundle of twistor space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, quaternionic-geometry

I am wondering whether there are cases, and if so whether some sufficient assumptions are know, when the twistor space of compact quaternionic/hypercomplex manifold has trivial canonical bundle. As those spaces are known **(edit: in general)** not to be Kähler I am interested in both topological and holomorphic triviality.

Comment: "As those spaces are known not to be Kähler" Could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes, what I meant while writing was a hyperKähler case - in which case I think it is well know, the reference I could find is https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/downloads/j9602330g. For quaternionic Kähler they may be (always are?) Kähler. I know nothing when dropping the additional metric assumption on the structure. Sorry for misleading statement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.